# Export 3d model as 2d image

Tags: 3d-view, export

I have created a 3d model in blender and I was wondering how can I export it as a 2d image.

For example, the game Clash of Clans the graphics are done in a 3d program and then exported as a 2d image ( that is what I have heard ).

Thanks!

Comment: You could render the model, save that as image and assign that image to some plane which then import somewhere.. like a sprite.

Comment: That process is called rendering, and is the staple of most every 3D model https://www.blender.org/manual/render/introduction.html

Comment: @MrZak can you perhaps answer the question?..Just be more detailed and I will choose it as the answer

Comment: Instead of commenting I mean

Comment: Blender Stack Exchange is not a tutorial site but I can recommend you for example this video on YT:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-grDsMg6_k
It looks like it should cover what you need to know (the basics of rendering.)